# The meaning of « voilà qui »

Tags: sens

> Elle a été retrouvée ? **Voilà qui** me rassure.

When « voilà » is followed by « qui », what is the exact meaning of the phrase? Is it close in meaning to:

> Elle a été retrouvée ? **Voilà ce qui** me rassure.

"She’s been found? **Here’s what** reassures me. {Now I’m relieved.}"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one is correct and is even a common saying. If it can help you, an acceptable traduction would be something along the lines of:

> She's been found ? Now **that** is some reassuring news !

The second one, *Voilà ce qui me rassure*, doesn't make sense here, though you're right in your translation. It is used to make a **list**, or more generally to point at something. For example, let's assume you're going on a trip and are making a list of things you didn't pack yet:

> **Voilà ce qui** me manque pour demain:
>
> 1. Des vêtements
> 2. Un sac de couchage
> 3. Etc.

Or another one: you had this feeling that you had forgotten something, but you didn't know what (damn that's a crap feeling). Then, you stumble upon your old game boy and realize that's what you were missing:

> **Voilà ce qui** me manquait !
>
> That's/Here's what I was missing !

Answer (score 2):

Il s'agit de mettre en évidence un phénomène. Le qui est un pronom relatif.

Source : [Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/voil%C3%A0/82372/locution?q=voila%20qui#184454)

Dans le contexte de votre phrase, vous mettez l'emphase sur le fait que vous êtes rassuré par ses retrouvailles.

Le second exemple, *Voilà ce qui me rassure.* n'est pas valide dans le contexte de votre exemple.

*Sorry for not answering in English.*

Comment: "Voilà ce qui me rassure" n'est pas faux, ça va convient juste pour autre chose, mais pas dans cet exemple.

Comment: Oui pardon, je voulais bien sur dire dans son contexte !

Answer (score 1):

I'm french native language and you're right in your conception of "voilà qui".
It's used to explain your feelings facing a news.

You can understand it like this :

> She's been found ? **That's news that** reassures me.

(Not in the past)

> Voila qui m'a rassuré

(This doesn't work)

Comment: "News" always has an "s" in English, and you have to use "that" instead of "who" because news are not people. Moreover, your suggestion is not a translation, more like paraphrasing.

Comment: @MorganFR - Thanks for your corrections :)

Comment: You forgot to remove "a" aswell, because news is uncountable. Also, it's "reassures" because "news" is singular even though it has to have an "s". For future reference: https://jakubmarian.com/news-is-vs-news-are-jeans-is-vs-jeans-are-etc-in-english/